# Can't access inner class member with outer class object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer
{
    int o;
public:
    void setOuter(int o)
    {
        this->o=o;
    }
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        int i;
        int retOuter(Outer *obj)
        {
            return obj->o;
        }
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Outer::Inner obj;
    obj.i=20;
    std::cout<<"Inner i = "<<obj.i<<std::endl;

    Outer *obj1=new Outer;
    obj1->setOuter(40);
    std::cout<<"Outer o = "<<obj.retOuter(obj1)<<std::endl;

    obj1->Inner::i =50; //Access the inner class members by Outer class object!
}
```

Everything in the above code is fine apart from the last line. Why I am not able to access the Inner class member with an Outer class object? Outer class object should have all the public member access of `class Outer` And how is the behavior when I create an Inner class object as it is contained by an Outer class!

Answer (score 5):

`Inner` is just a class defined at a different scope. It's no different than saying

```
class Inner
{
public:
    int i;
    int retOuter(Outer *obj)
    {
        return obj->o;
    }
};
```

and then

```
Inner::i =50
```

which obviously isn't possible because `i` isn't `static`.

Declaring an inner class doesn't automagically declare a member of that type for the outer class which you can access using that syntax.

Now, something like:

```
class Outer
{
    int o;
public:
    void setOuter(int o)
    {
        this->o=o;
    }
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        int i;
        int retOuter(Outer *obj)
        {
            return obj->o;
        }
    } innerMember;
    //    ^^^
    // declare a member
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Outer *obj1=new Outer;
    obj1->innerMember.i =50; //Access the inner class members by Outer class object!
}
```

would work.

Comment: Ok. Then how the Outer class object have its own Inner class `i` value? Do I need to create object for the Inner class as `obj1->Inner objInner; objInner.i =50;`

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy as your code is, the Outer class doesn't have a member of type Inner. See my snipped for how to do that.

Comment: Yes your code snippet perfectly works. To clarify my understanding the Inner class then is not the member of the Outer class like other normal members. Right? Actually the Inner class definition is working as a type of `innerMember`. Am I right? same as `int innerMember`